# C++ : how is a reference to the value of a pointer is updated when the pointer itself changes?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider the following program:

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int *ptr = new int(10);
    int &ref = *ptr;

    cout << ref << endl << &ref << endl;

    delete ptr;
    ptr = new int(100);
    cout << ref << endl << &ref << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
    10
    0x80010348
    100
    0x80010348

Here the `ref` variable is a reference to the memory location pointed by `ptr`. However, when the `ptr` pointer is deleted and a new memory location is assigned, `ref` should now be referring to an undefined memory location as the previous does not exist. But when I run this program I get the updated value and address through ref with g++ on cygwin/linux as well as VC++2012 express.

However, if ptr is *not* deleted, then `ref` is not updated, and the output shows the old value 10 and old address. Is this behavior standard or is it compiler specific? If it's standard then why the update of `ref` depends upon whether `ptr` is deleted or not?

Comment: try outputting the second value of ptr too, it happens sometimes that coincidentally you get the same address.

Comment: It's _undefined behavior_. It could work, or it could crash your program.

Comment: Does it work everytime? This smells like undefined behavior...

Comment: Try allocating another variable before re-allocating ptr

Comment: It's how memory allocation works. It happened to give you the same address in second call to new, so it would appear 'updated'.

Comment: Yes, I also suspected this is a non-standard behavior, although happens consistently. Thanks for clarifications!

Answer (score 2):

It's just the way the memory allocator happens to work. In your code:

```
delete ptr;
ptr = new int(100);
```

you delete one `int` and then you immediately ask for a new one. The runtime says "Fine, have this one. It was just made available".

Simple recycling.